# jQuery Ajax, JSONP issue - readyState 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a jQuery Ajax call to a Java web-services. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
          type : 'GET',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          crossdomain: true,
          url : url,
          contentType : "application/json",
          success : function(response) {
              alert(JSON.stringify(response));
          },
          error: function(error){
              alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
          }
});
```

I always get error as:

```
{"readyState":"4","status":"200","statusText":"success"}
```

I am able to see the successfull data from my server side, but this issue I have from client side. One thing to mention is if I run from desktop browsers like Chrome, IE etc. It works fine. But if I run from mobile browser, I face this issue. We have our server configured for JSONP but still this issue persists. Can anyone please help me in this regard I am stuck in this from morning?

Comment: Why do you have `contentType : "application/json",`? You are making a GET request. There is no request body to specify the content type of.

Comment: @Quentin I tried by removing that `contentType`. Same issue still persists.

Comment: Have you looked into adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header from server side?

Comment: @PradeepSimha — The content-type of nonsense. Not the cause of your problem. That's why it was a comment.

Comment: @artm — JSONP is not subject to the same origin policy.

Comment: Look at the response in the net tab of your browser's developer tools. Is it the JSONP you expect?